# calculating min and max of 2-D array in c

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

This program to calculate sum,min and max of the sum of array elements
Max value is the problem, it is always not true.

```
void main(void)
{
    int  degree[3][2];
        int min_max[][];
    int Max=min_max[0][0];
    int Min=min_max[0][0];
    int i,j;
    int sum=0;

    clrscr();
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<2;j++)
        {
            printf("\n enter degree of student no. %d in subject %d:",i+1,j+1);
            scanf("%d",&degree[i][j]);
        }

    }


    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<2;j++)
        {
            printf("\n Student no. %d degree in subject no. %d is %d",i+1,j+1,degree[i][j]);

        }

    }


    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        sum=0;
        for(j=0;j<2;j++)
        {
            sum+=degree[i][j];

        }
        printf("\n sum of degrees of student no. %d is %d",i+1,sum);
        min_max[i][j]=sum;
        if(min_max[i][j] <Min)
        {
            Min=min_max[i][j];
        }
        else if(min_max[i][j]>Max)
        {
            Max=min_max[i][j];
        }




    }
    printf("\nThe minimum sum of degrees of student no. %d is %d",i,Min);
    printf("\nThe maximum sum of degrees of student no. %d is %d",i,Max);
    getch();

}
```

Comment: That won't even compile; post your actual code.

Comment: i'm tried to write it again.When i use <pre>tag, some lines are deleted.

Comment: you just need to write your code indented by 4 spaces, and it will be automagically formatted as code :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are initialising Min and Max to min_max[0][0] *before* assigning any values to min_max, so their content is actually undefined.

Put the assignments `Min=min_max[0][0]` and `Max=min_max[0][0]` AFTER the `scanf` calls.

Answer (score 0):

The lines

```
printf("\nThe minimum sum of degrees is %d",i,Min);
printf("\nThe maximum sum of degrees  is %d",i,Max);
```

will print the only value of `i`, not `Min` or `Max`.  Try this instead:

```
printf("\nThe minimum sum of degrees for %d is %d",i,Min);
printf("\nThe maximum sum of degrees for %d is %d",i,Max);
```

The line

```
min_max[i][j]=sum;
```

will always have a value of 2 for `j` because it is outside of the `for` loop.  Also, I'm not clear why you would want to store the partial sum of degrees in the min_max array?

Comment: i want to store the partial sum of degrees in the min_max array because i want to have the min and max of sum of degrees

Comment: Then there is no reason to define the min_max array in the code you wrote; min_max[i][j] is currently ONLY used as a copy of `sum`.

Comment: yes
Do u mean i should write if (sum<min){min=sum;}
if so, what is the initial value of min and max will be.

Comment: Initial value for Max can be 0, initial value for Min can be something large like 2000000000.